# Converting Color Images to Grayscale but shape of the image stays identical

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I've converted some images from RGB to Grayscale for ML purpose.
However the shape of the converted grayscale image is still 3, the same as the color image.

The code for the Conversion:

```py
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('path/to/color/image')
imgGray = img.convert('L')
imgGray.save('path/to/grayscale/image')
```

The code to check the shape of the images:

```py
import cv2
im_color = cv2.imread('path/to/color/image')
print(im_color.shape)
im_gray2 = cv2.imread('path/to/grayscale/image')
print(im_gray2.shape)
```

Comment: Use skimage library. Function: rgb2gray(). You will have a single layer grayscale image as your output. Just make sure that you have the RGB image as a numpy ndarray.

Comment: Why are you using PIL and OpenCV - you rarely need both and it tends to lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You did

```
im_gray2 = cv2.imread('path/to/grayscale/image')
```

OpenCV does not inspect colorness of image - it does assume image is color and desired output is BGR 8-bit format. You need to inform OpenCV you want output to be grayscale (2D intensity array) as follows

```
im_gray2 = cv2.imread('path/to/grayscale/image', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

If you want to know more about reading images read [OpenCV: Getting Started with Images](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/db/deb/tutorial_display_image.html)

Answer (score 0):

`cv.imread`, *without any flags*, will always convert any image content to BGR, 8 bits per channel.

If you want any image file, grayscale or color, to be **read as grayscale**, you can pass the `cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` flag.

If you want to read the file **as it really is**, then you need to use **`cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`**.

```py
im_color = cv2.imread('path/to/color/image', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(im_color.shape)
im_gray2 = cv2.imread('path/to/grayscale/image', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(im_gray2.shape)
```